# How to find max&min of all variables with SPSS and display in table?

Tags: macros, spss

I have a table with about 500 variables and 2000 cases.  The type of these variables varies.  My supervisor has asked me to produce a table listing all the numeric variables, along with their maximums and minimums.  I am supposed to use SPSS because R apparently messes up the value labels.

I've only done very basic things in SPSS before this, like finding statistics for single variables, and I'm not sure how to do this.  I think I should probably do something like:

```
*Create new table*
DATASET DECLARE maxAndMin.
*Loop through all variables: Use conditional statement to identify numeric variables*
DO REPEAT R=var1 TO varN.
FREQUENCIES VARIABLES /STATISTICS=MINIMUM
END REPEAT
*Find max and minimum*
```

I'm not sure how to go about this though.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will first make a list of all numeric variables in the dataset (and store it in a macro called `!nums`) and then it will run an analysis of those variables to tell you the mean, maximum and minimum of each:

```
SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME="!nums" /PROPERTIES TYPE= NUMERIC.
DESCRIPTIVES !nums /STATISTICS=MEAN MIN MAX.
```

You can use the following code to create a tiny dataset to test the above code on:

```
data list list/n1 (f1) t1(a1) n2(f1) t2(a1).
begin data
1 "a" 34 "b"
2 "a" 23 "b"
3 "a" 52 "b"
4 "a" 71 "b"
end data.
```

Comment: Thanks!  Follow-up question:  When I use these commands on a larger dataset such as plantar_fascitiitis.csv here, https://www.kaggle.com/rameessahlu/plantar-fasciitis, I find that the variables in the output table aren't listed in the same order as they appear in the original table (ie. the variables are listed in a seemingly random order (Status, TendernessOfFoot, alignment, burning), vs. the original order (id, age, sex, weight)).  Why does this occur, and is there any way to force the variables to be listed in the same order in the output table as they are listed in the input table?

Comment: Interesting question, I'll have to research that. Please post this as a new question though.

Comment: Here, thanks!: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58700525/how-to-order-variables-in-spss-output-table-same-as-variables-in-original-table

Answer (score 0):

If SUMMARIZE produces a nice enough table for you, here is a "non-extension" way of doing it.

```
file handle mydata /name="<whatever/wherever>".

data list free /x (f1) y (a5) z (F4.2).
begin data.
1 yes 45.67
2 no 32.00
3 maybe .
4 yes 22.02
5 no 12.79
end data.

oms select tables
 /destination format=sav outfile=mydata
 /if subtypes="Descriptive Statistics" /tag="x".
des var all.
omsend tag="x".

get file mydata.
summarize Var1 Mean Minimum Maximum /format list nocasenum nototal
 /cells none /statistics none /title "Numeric Variables Only".
```

or use a  `DATASET` command instead of file handle if you don't need the file on disk.